# plsql como comparar las mismas columnas de una tabla

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

tengo que realizar un ejercicio en el que tengo que sacar el número de empleados que ganan mas salario que otro apellidado 'MILLAN', no se muy bien como encaminarlo, ¿alguien tiene alguna idea? estoy empezando a usar plsql

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Bienvenido, es importante realizar preguntas en base a el documento [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), **te sugerimos editar tu pregunta y agregar lo que has tratado o investigado**. No olvides realizar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) del sitio para conocer su funcionamiento básico, saludos.

Comment: Se puede resolver usando solo sql, no es necesario un script en pl. La clave está en usar dos veces la tabla empleados con diferente alias. Asi podes hacer la parte del select referenciando uno de los alias y la parte de la condición (where) referenciando el otro alias.

Answer (score 0):

Tengo un poco oxidado el PSQL, pero la esencia es que hagas un JOIN en la tabla empleados para sacar el empleado apellidado 'MILLAN' (e) y luego con un WHERE simplemente comparas el salario de los otros empleados con el de 'MILLAN' (e).

Importante hacer uso de la función de agregación `count(*)` en el `SELECT`, que te permite sacar el número de empleados que cumplen las condiciones que hemos planteado.

Esto sería un ejemplo, no me tengas en cuenta la sintaxis que llevo bastante tiempo sin tocar SQL directamente:

```sql
SELECT count(*) FROM empleados
JOIN empleados e ON e.apellido = 'MILLAN'
WHERE empleados.salario > e.salario;
```